# Terminal or ADB command to force-stop applications

Tags: adb, terminal

What is the terminal or adb command to force-stop an application?

Like for freezing we use `pm disable application_name`.

Comment: `killall application_pkg_name` also works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `am force-stop <package name>`. Also there is `am kill <package name>`.

Comment: Just to be clear: `am kill` only kills "processes that are safe to kill": i.e. a process with no running services or activities.