# Touchscreen inputs without user interaction?

Tags: automation, touchscreen, user-interface, task-management, force-close

Consider the following system:

- Stock Android 9, unrooted
- USB and wireless debugging unavailable
- screen permanently turned off

So basically a headless Android device.

**Question:** Is it possible to programmatically execute touchscreen inputs without any user interaction, e.g. in order to automatically force-stop selected apps?

**Example:** The default method to do this manually is from the app info menu, i.e.

[image: Force-closing active apps by user input]

Similarly, inactive/background apps can be closed from the developer settings:

[image: Force-closing inactive apps by user input]

**Note:** A purely programmatic solution is required. Connection to a debugging device is allowed only once for initial setup, otherwise: No external devices.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is kill apps, you can use ADB commands: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45202/terminal-or-adb-command-to-force-stop-applications

Comment: @jlehenbauer How can you use `adb` on a headless Android device without remote debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this restriction:

> USB and wireless debugging unavailable

...is specifically referring to USB *debugging*, and that the USB port is still functional for general-purpose use.

Judging from your example navigation flows, I'm also going to assume that the Android device screen is in some semblance of a PIN-"unlocked" and usable state at the software level, even if the physical display is off.

Per the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/usb), Android has had support for USB mice since 3.1:

> In USB host mode, the Android-powered device acts as the host. Examples of devices include digital cameras, keyboards, mice, and game controllers.
> [...]
> USB accessory and host modes are directly supported in Android 3.1 (API level 12) or newer platforms.

So, you can use some form of USB-connected hardware emulation device (often referred to as a "rubber ducky") to simulate mouse activity and navigate to the relevant menus. [This blog post](https://blog.jfedor.org/2020/09/usb-rubber-ducky-with-mouse-input.html) has more information on how that can be accomplished.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems you didn't understand the question text, which reads: **"Is it possible to *programmatically* execute touchscreen inputs *without any user interaction [...]?*"** The goal is to *automate* touchscreen inputs such that **no user input is required**. Connecting and using an external HID (such as a USB or WiFi keyboard, mouse, or touchpad) precisely constitutes a form of user input, which we want to avoid!

Comment: Connecting a USB device one time to run some automation in an infinite loop only requires user input to the same extent as, e.g., installing some software that might have the same effect (unfortunately not really possible on Android with your restrictions). There obviously needs to be user input to set up a solution.

Comment: After re-reading your comment, I'm not convinced that you actually read my original solution correctly. I'm referring to using an HID *emulation device*, i.e., something that automatically sends simulated "user inputs" to the phone. This would not require any user interaction after being plugged in.

Comment: I perfectly understand your suggestion. Again, please read the question and my comment below your answer carefully: 1.) USB is not available, 2.) a programmatic solution is required. I will certainly not carry around an "additional device" permanently attached to my *mobile* phone - this is a ridiculous suggestion. Please stop insisting on your hardware solution, we need a programmatic solution.

Comment: Also, your definition of user input seems intentionally distorted. *Obviously*, we're not excluding any form of physical interaction with the device, as this would render everything impossible. *Obviously*, the script/app needs to be installed initially. "User input" here as well as in 99% of all other use cases means *manual touchscreen inputs by the user* during normal runtime, after initial setup.

Comment: For the third time, my solution did not require any manual inputs during normal runtime. You've laid out an absurd situation with your question. I can assure you, there is no solution that won't be equally absurd to fit the requirements you laid out. Why on earth would anyone carry a mobile phone around if the screen was *permanently* off? In such a ridiculous scenario, obviously strange solutions like a small hardware peripheral would have to be considered. But seeing as you don't like that answer, I doubt you'll ever have a solution to your extremely contrived situation.